# How to remove extra space from left of expandable search view in action bar and show two more menu options compulsorily?

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to remove extra space which is before expanded searchView, and there is one more menu icon which needs to be shown with these two icons compulsorily.

Searched many questions related to this, but none of the solutions seem to be working.

[image: Expanded search view image]

Answer (score 1):

If you need only reduce padding between navigation icon and logo, use `Toolbar.setContentInsetStartWithNavigation(0)`

Unlike contentInsetStart, this will modify the inset only when there is a navigation icon. If there's no navigation icon, you will still have the `16dp` start inset.

Answer (score 0):

This will work with custom toolbool.

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
      xmlns:app="schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:background="@color/primaryColor"
      android:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
      android:contentInsetStart="0dp"
      app:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
      app:contentInsetStart="0dp" />
```

Comment: This will remove padding from all other screens also.

Comment: this for Toolbar

Comment: yeah. So i have many more screens using the same toolbar. And more over by doing this also, it is not allowing me to add 2 more icons.

Answer (score 0):

Be Sure To add your other 2 Menus with The Search Widget with Explicit Command to Show always in your menu that will show on the Toolbar.

Example Below shows 3 Menu items with the Search View widget a show As Action of if Room which displays it whenever there is room on the toolbar. Likewise for the other 2 menu items.

The spacing shall happen seamlessly.

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
tools:context=".activities.ScrollingActivity">  


<item
    android:id="@+id/action_search"
    android:title="@string/search_hint"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_search_white_24dp"
    app:showAsAction="collapseActionView|ifRoom"
    app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView" />

<item
    android:id="@+id/profile"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:title="@string/profile"
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom" />

<item
    android:id="@+id/credits"
    android:orderInCategory="101"
    android:title="@string/credits"
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom" />
</menu>
```

Get the searchview by its ID in the activity in OnCreateOptionsMenu.

For Example

SearchView searchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.action_search).getActionView();

searchItem.expandActionView();

Comment: This will make search icon collapsable. I need it in expanded mode always with no way to collapse it.